# Thunderbird: launch browser directly, instead via gio-launch-desktop

Tags: browser, thunderbird

When I click on URL link in `Thunderbird`, instead of opening the link in browser directly, it calls `gio-launch-desktop` which in turns then starts  a browser.

I am sure there must be some option in Thunderbird preferences, to specify my preferred browser, so that when I click on a link, Thunderbird opens the link in this browser.

Is there such an option?
How can I tell Thunderbird I want to use `chromium` as default browser ?

Comment: I use [Open With](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/open-with/) which lets me right click on URLs and pick which browser to open them with. It's not quite what you're after, but it's an option you may want to try. If you choose a browser that's already open, it opens the links in a new tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure Chromium is set for `mimeapps.list`'s `x-scheme-handler` at least for user overrides, it might be Thunderbird did not find the path correct at `NC:path` in [MimeTypes.rdf](http://kb.mozillazine.org/MimeTypes.rdf), where the other profile defaults set:

```
  <RDF:Description RDF:about="urn:scheme:externalApplication:http"
                   NC:prettyName="firefox"
                   NC:path="/usr/bin/firefox" />
```

Sorry for the short answer. You may want to read more at GNOME's GLib docs and how it [is replaced](https://github.com/GNOME/glib/commit/8f7faac10fe71c8d8bd5acefa894c4ffa03a2ad4) by `sh`.